# Click uncovered portion of element below another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

[image]


I have two elements, `input[type="text"]` and `select`, the `select` is beneath the `input` but a small portion of the `select` is not covered (the dropdown arrow). However, I still can't click the `select`'s dropdown arrow.

I still need both of them to function normally, that's why I'm not using `pointer-events: none;` to the `input`.

The `input` uses `float: left` while the `select` uses `position: relative` and `z-index: -1`

**PUG (HTML)**

```
input#search-box(type="text")
select#search-by
  option(value="o1") Sample 1
  option(value="o2") Sample 2
  option(value="o3") Sample 3
```

**Stylus (CSS)**

```
#search-box {
  float left
  margin 7px 0px 0px 10px
  height 50%
  width 215px
  display inline-block
  vertical-align middle
}

#s2id_search-by {
  position relative
  top -43px
  left 2px
  z-index -1
}
#s2id_search-by a {
  height 33px
  width 234px
}
```

For the libraries involved in this part of my code, I'm using `select2.js` for the select

How can I make this design to work? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code here....

Comment: I've added the code to my question, @Mukesh